# Is there a statically-typed language that works on both the JVM and CLR?

Tags: programming-languages, jvm, clr, static-typing

I am writing code that I want to eventually execute on the PC, Xbox, and Android platforms, and if possible also Mac and Linux. Instead of rewriting it for each platform, I'd like to write it once in a language that will work on all of those platforms. I've considered Fantom, but apparently it doesn't work on Android, and it has limited support for static typing and generics, and I've heard that Scala is going to work on the CLR, but it currently doesn't support CLR generics, which prevents it from being used with XNA. I don't want to use a dynamically typed language because dynamic typing runs slower (particularly important on smartphones) and is harder to debug.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to target JVM? If this need is solely to handle Android then probably take a look at [MonoTouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch) which is a .NET stack for popular mobile platforms being developed by Xamarin (those folks who were behind Mono when it was developed back then at Novell).  Mono itself is a way to target Mac and other POSIX platforms using [X Window System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) for graphical interaction (what you called "Linux").

You should be aware though that you still might need to re-write GUI parts for various platforms anyway: first, the approach to interfaces used on touchscreen devices differs rather strongly from that on "desktop" devices, and secnd, while MonoTouch will probably provide for unified UI on the platforms it targets (Android, iOS, WinPhone) desktop Windows, Mac and X-based platforms have their own *preferred* GUI stacks available through .NET or Mono—WPF or Winforms on Windows, [MonoMac](http://www.mono-project.com/MonoMac) on Mac OS X (using Cocoa) and [Gtk#](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp) on POSIX platforms using X.  Mono seems to provide unified GUI stack for all these desktop platforms since it [does support Winforms](http://www.mono-project.com/Winforms) but the overall look-and-feel *might* be suboptimal on platforms other than Windows so you'll have to look.

But at least the core program logic will not need be ported to each platform.

P.S.
Also note that most modern JVM-based software stacks I managed to look at on various occasions supported CLR via [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/) which kind of "wraps" CLR pretending it's JVM in the eyes of Java code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Scala, while typically used on the [JVM](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/25). also has some [CLR support](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/10299). Clojure isn't statically-typed, but I believe it also does (or did) support both the JVM and CLR.